# Grouping a List of Key Value Dictionaries in c# using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` Key pairs:

[image]

How would I write my Linq query so that I have only 1 Dictionary where the Values are grouped by key?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Linq has `GroupBy` and `ToDictionary`

Comment: Provide some code what you have tried so far. What is the error you encountered if any? This is not a "Comunity, do the work for me" platform.

Comment: Also..... It seems like you can replace those dictionaries with a class that has 4 properties

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Yes I've tried some things and yes I've tried using GroupBy and I'm not 100% sure on how to use ToDictionary. Wow this community can be really poisonous at times. I only posted here as my last resort. Yes creating a class would be the easiest way but the framework I'm using already has this exact class with these properties but for reasons I'd rather not get into I am unable to create an instance of this class. Therefore I would have to create an almost exact duplicate of this class to create an instance of it and store my properties.

Comment: @JoshL - Didn't downvote but about "Wow this community can be really poisonous at times" - Please refer to the How To Ask... If you do not show what you have tried.. Then how can we know that you even tried?..

Comment: The ouput I'm looking for would have all the values for Category Key grouped together, all the values for the Role Key grouped somewhere etc..

Comment: @GiladGreen yea you're right, personally I prefer when questions are as precise as possible so I can read through it quickly and get to the answer but in the future I will try and provide a brief overview of what I've tried

Comment: @JoshL - Most of the times people are close to the answer they need - so it is best to show them, on their code, what was the little things they missed - That is how you turn people into better programmers...

Comment: @GiladGreen Thank you I appreciate any constructive feedback and will certainly keep this in mind for next time :) . I was not referring to you when I said "this community can be poisonous"

Comment: @JoshL - It is fine :) wasn't offended. I don't tend to downvote users, especially if they are new (by reputation) - it is part of how one learns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = data.SelectMany(item => item)
    .GroupBy(item => item.Key)
    .ToDictionary(key => key.Key, value => value.Select(i => i.Value).ToList());
```

For given input:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["Category"] = "99",
        ["Role"] = "11",
        ["Level"] = "22",
        ["BillaleDays"] = "33",
    },
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["Category"] = "55",
        ["Role"] = "66",
        ["Level"] = "77",
        ["BillaleDays"] = "88",
    }
};
```

Result is:

```
Category : (99,55)
Role : (11,66)
Level : (22,77)
BillableDays : (33,88)
```

Comment: @Josh L - Glad it helped :)

Comment: Works like a charm ! I was not using the .ToDictionary function properly. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {        
        ["Name"] = "one",
        ["Age"] = "22"
    },
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["Name"] = "two",
        ["Age"] = "88",
    }
};

var result = data.SelectMany(item => item)
                 .GroupBy(item => item.Key)
                 .ToDictionary(key => key.Key, value => value.Select(i => i.Value).ToList());
```

Output:
`Name:"one,"two",
Age:"22","88"`

Comment: This is very close to what I want, however I want to group by Key not value, so that one key has multiple values associated with it.

Comment: you can replace key inplace of value and vice versa

Dictionary<int,List<string>> test  = 
               sample .GroupBy(r=> r.key)
              .ToDictionary(t=> t.value, t=> t.Select(r=> r.value).ToList());

Comment: @Josh i have edited my answer according to your requirement, try it once and let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: @Meena - it is almost correct. You are just missing the `List<Dictionary>` part. Correct that and it will be a good answer too :)

Comment: @Meena - It currently does not compile

Comment: @Gilad i changed it.